# Kibana Dashboard from Multiple Indices

Tags: couchdb, kibana, dashboard

I have a Couch DB server that stores a number of sets of logs. Each of these is pulled into elastic search via a river. This works fine. Each of the indices has a timestamp field (the same field name in each index). I am trying to create a kibana dashboard which shows all a number of charts, one for each index. The problem I'm having is that there doesn't seem to be a way to distinguish which index each chart is built from. Is this possible or do I have to have a dashboard per index?

Comment: If you have a different query for each series, you can select just that query for a panel in the customize option.

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom dashboards depending upon the index. Create a new dashboard and visualize upon custom fields and add it to dashboard.

Likewise create new dashboard and you can add visualizations of another index.

Now you can monitor with different dashboards.

Answer (score -1):

You may be able to use an alias that points to multiple indexes. Then create multiple queries.

[Alias with multiple indices](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/multiple-indices.html)